# How to Get The Output Like This

Tags: appendices

```
Appendix A: 
 Table A.1 
 Table A.2  

Appendix B:  
 Table B.1 
 Table B.2 

Appendix C:
 Table C.1 
 Table C.2
```

How to Get output like this

Comment: Only in the Appendix B are the tables put in a different line?

Comment: Appendix A
  A.1 Usecase1
  A.2 Usecase2
Appendix B
  B.1 Usecase1
  B.2 Usecase2
Appendix C
  C.1 Usecase1
  C.2 Usecase2

i wan't get out put like this...plz help me as soon as posible

Comment: Who understand this question?

Comment: @Madusanka: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. This makes it a lot easier for us to see exactly what it is you are trying to do, even if it doesn't work (yet).

Comment: **@Whoever voted to close**: We usually don't close a question for formal reasons one hour after it was asked. Let's give Madusanka the opportunity to improve the question. (However, I agree that the question, in its current form, ought to be closed; but I'm hopeful that it won't stay like this.)

Comment: It is really not clear what you want to achieve: You want to modify the List of Tables?

Comment: @doncherry A closed question can always be edited by author and then reopened by a vote.

Comment: @PaulGaborit: Yes, but our newbie-friendly (and everybody else-friendly) approach is to give users at least 24 hours to fix their question before closing it, in order to avoid scaring anybody away. (I interpret the high number of upvotes for my earlier comment that I managed to decently accurately reflect the community's sentiment.) *However*, while the question is in a state indicating its need to be closed, it should not be answered.

Answer (score 1):

May be like this?!

[image]

**Code:**

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% \usepackage{appendix} %% More useful. refer documentation. texdoc appendix from command prompt.
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
\listoftables
\cleardoublepage
%\listoffigures
%\cleardoublepage
\chapter{Abstract}
\lipsum[1-2]
\mainmatter
\chapter{Test chapter}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\caption{Some other table}
 A table
\end{table}
\section{First section}
\lipsum[1-5]
\appendix
%\begin{appendix} %% You can also use the environment instead of \appendix
\chapter{Appendix first}
\section{Use case one}
\begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\caption{Some other table}
 A table
\end{table}
\section{Use case two}
\begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\caption{Some other table}
 A table
\end{table}
\chapter{Appendix second}
\section{Use case one}
\begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\caption{Some other table}
 A table
\end{table}
\section{Use case two}
\begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\caption{Some other table}
 A table
\end{table}
%\end{appendix}
\backmatter

\end{document}
```